# What would be the code to add and subtract fractions in c++

Tags: c++

I wrote a program to multiply, divide, add, and subtract fractions..I just can't figure out what the formula would be to add and subtract them. What would It be?

my code so far:

```
   Fraction subtractFractions(Fraction numDen, Fraction numDen2)
{
Fraction value;
value.numerator=numDen.numerator-numDen2.numerator;
if(numDen.denominator!=numDen2.denominator){
    value.denominator=numDen2.denominator/numDen.denominator;
    value.numerator*=value.denominator;
    value.denominator*=value.denominator;
    value.numerator=numDen.numerator-numDen2.numerator;
}
return value;
}
```

As you can see..its in a function..my add and subtract functions are the same code so I just posted one

Comment: The same as when you're adding or subtracting fractions on paper.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, and where you are stuck and we may be able to give some pointers.

Comment: Is your goal to keep them in fractional form?  That is less trivial.

Comment: I've never been good with adding and subtracting fractions..thus the reason im having such a hard time writing this part.

Comment: @user1443074: if you don't know how to do it on paper how can you expect to code it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a/b - c/d = (ad - bc) / bd
```

Then you need to reduce that to lowest terms (if you care about that).

Answer (score 12):

I assume you store the numbers in the format int a, int b, to represent a/b. For addition you need to do:

```
a1    a2   a1*b2+a2*b1
--  + -- = -----------
b1    b2      b1*b2
```

subtraction works in the same way. As a next step you should think about how to reduce fractions.

Comment: Ooh, pretty ascii fraction art! +1